# Crop the Image as a square in windows phone 7 for jigsaw Puzzle Game

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Please Help me, I want to Crop the Image as a Square by Square for Jigsaw Puzzle Game App. How Should I do That in Windows Phone 7

Comment: You haven't stated what you've tried. However, this should point you in the right direction: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should use photoshop instead or anyother image editing software.